# UIColor preview tool?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, colors, rgb, uicolor

Say I have

```
UIColor *blue = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.65 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8];
```

Is there any online tool I can use to preview this values, so I can find what color I want exactly. Im not sure what these decimals are called. Its not RGB or hexadecimal so I dont know what it is..

Comment: By the way, you can use IB to preview your color using RGB values.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565008).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* RGB. Since the range is 0 to 1, you need to multiply by 255 to the first three components to get (166, 255, 255) with an alpha (opacity) of 80%.

You could try http://jsbin.com/ilowi5/3 which displays those UIColor in a browser that supports RGBA (e.g. Firefox and Chrome).