# Weird colors in XCode Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, colors, interface-builder

I have really weird problem with colors in interface builder. I set a color on one UI element, for example UIView, and then I want the same color on UIButton...but when I try to do so, colors are often different - I mean little bit different tone, not absolutely different color. How is this even possible ??? I've tried to use RGB sliders, and other sliders, also that color picker tool... Only thing that helps me sometimes is, when I create new UI element. Anybody had the same problem and knows what's going on ?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Interface Builder filters colors through your monitor's current color space by default. You can change this in Xcode4 IB by bringing up a Colors dialog, clicking the Sliders tab, then clicking the little dropdown button under the magnifying glass that looks like a color spectrum. This will bring up a list of available color spaces -- select **Generic RGB** and adjust the sliders as necessary to get the correct color.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565008/how-do-i-enter-rgb-values-into-interface-builder) for more information, especially the comments on the accepted answer.

Comment: Deserves way more up votes. This has been bugging me for literally *years*.

Comment: Apple wants appearances to be uniform regardless of the hardware, so it adjusts views accordingly.  This question provides a bit more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578759/wrong-color-in-interface-builder

Comment: If you want to copy RGB values from Photoshop exactly (without conversion between color spaces), this answer explains how:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14581553/539149

Comment: When I change the color space it reverts back to sRGB when I move the sliders or input a value.

Comment: @Bot it seems to only revert back to sRGB when the hex value field becomes active, which if you're tabbing will be after tabbing off blue. So in order to keep Generic RGB just click the red or green field after setting blue. I figured this out by mousing over the color swatch in the bottom left, it will tell you the profile.

Comment: I've got Generic RGB selected by default but I'm still seeing a mismatch.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this issue using "Device RGB" instead "Generic RGB".
See the image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, fiddling with color spaces didn't work for me. What *did* work was editing the raw xml of the .xib (right click .xib, Open As > Source Code) and changing the RGB decimal values there.

Answer (score -1):

The currently selected item in interface builder will be slightly different to its actual colour - it has a darkened mask applied to it to highlight the fact that it is selected. You need to click somewhere else in the window to unselect the item, it's real colour will then be shown. I've fallen into this trap myself.

Comment: no, no :) that's not it...of course I clicked somewhere else, I also ran the project, colors are different

Comment: Worth a try... can you put a screenshot somewhere?