# Interface Builder colour different to code color

Tags: ios, colors, interface-builder

What is different here that I'm missing. I haven't noticed this before, or I'm doing something stupid.....

Got a view in interface builder, set its background colour using RGB sliders 44, 44, 44. Opactity 1. Set as opaque.

When I run the app, it has changed it to 33, 33, 33 ????

If in the view will appear, I change it using....

```
self.topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:44.0f/255.0f green:44.0f/255.0f blue:44.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

..then everything is ok.

What is doing this?

It happens with any colour. If i choose 200, 250, 5 - i run the app and it has changed to 200, 120, 5 ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird colors in XCode Interface Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488378/weird-colors-in-xcode-interface-builder)

Comment: Not quite, but I found the answer in one of the comments of another post that linked to the post you just gave me! Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to choose the correct colorspace...

Thanks to a comment by Ken from this post

[Other question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565008/how-do-i-enter-rgb-values-into-interface-builder)

> Actually, be careful with the magnifying glass. Just component numbers
>   do not spec a color, you also need to know the colorspace. It's like
>   string encodings. 65 is the ASCII encoding of A. The colorspace with
>   which to encode/decode the components is in the little dropdown to the
>   left of "RGB" sliders above. The "Generic RGB" colorspace corresponds
>   to colors made with +[NSColor
>   colorWithCalibratedRed:green:blue:alpha:]. If you use the magnifying
>   glass, the components will be given with respect to "device" space
>   which means the current screen. This is not appropriate. Select
>   generic after

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, be sure you're setting the opacity to 100%, not 1%. (Your question states that you're setting it to 1.)

Comment: I was setting it to 1.0 in the code. 100% in IB. See my answer for the correct answer that solved. Never knew about these colour spaces!