# Xcode 6 beta color picker issue

Tags: xcode, xcode6, color-picker

Problem: The color picker isn't picking up the exact color. This is the same problem listed here: [Wrong color in Interface Builder's color picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686141/wrong-color-in-interface-builders-color-picker)

I've tried:

1. Color picker -> gear button next to sliders -> select Generic RGB.
2. System Preferences -> Displays -> Color Profile -> Generic RGB Profile.
3. Disabled any apps that may affect color profile (Datacolor SpyderPro, Flux).

I've looked at these questions already:

[Wrong color in Interface Builder's color picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686141/wrong-color-in-interface-builders-color-picker)

[Weird colors in XCode Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488378/weird-colors-in-xcode-interface-builder/9203647#9203647)

[Wrong color in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578759/wrong-color-in-interface-builder)

I've tried their answers and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the colorPicker is changing the colorProfile to sRGB if you change the RGB or the HEX-Values over and over again.

BUT if you change the profile to "Apple RGB" and choose the desired RGB-Values via the slider the profile will not change! I have been able to select the needed color this way - hope it helps...

(under some circumstances (which I unfortunately cannot reproduce yet) the profile will not be changed during entering the rgb-value)