# Why if I set a color to my navigation controller bar it looks different from photoshop or any app?

Tags: swift, colors, uinavigationcontroller, uicolor

It's simple. I use this color: #00ac00 and RGB (0,172,0). In photoshop for example the color is what I exactly need. But once I program it in Xcode it looks way more bright, like psychedelic. This is my code to set the color:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 172, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
```

The only thing I could do is set a pattern image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring up the Colors dialog then Click on the Slider tab then select **Generic RGB**. ' be careful not to switch between slider options as this converts it back to sRGB values.

Another option is to uncheck "Covert to sRGB option in Photoshop When you choose "Save for Web & Devices" from Photoshop, uncheck the "Convert to sRGB" box.

Why does this happen, because apple stores the values of the display along with RGB value. This causes a issue with photoshop color correction Mechanism (colorspace).

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488378/weird-colors-in-xcode-interface-builder)

[Understanding Color Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686141/wrong-color-in-interface-builders-color-picker)

[Apple Built in Color Mechanism vs Photoshop Built in Color Mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578759/wrong-color-in-interface-builder/14581553#14581553)