# UIButton title color RGB values programmatically different than what was set in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicolor

I added a UIButton to my view. It's a regular button of system type, default config and plain title, all default values. I set the text color property in IB to the RGB values shown below: r68, g66, b62
[image: UIButton title color]

I made a custom color programmatically with the same RGB values:

```
extension UIColor {

    class var customColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 68/255, green: 66/255, blue: 62/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Why are the button's RGB values different when I check them in my view controller than what I set them to be in IB (identical to my custom color RGB values)?

```
// UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.33669 0.327454 0.310221 1
myButton.titleColor(for: .normal)!.description)

// UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.266667 0.258824 0.243137 1
UIColor.customColor.description
```

Shouldn't they be the same? If not, how do I get them to be the same?

Comment: It's the color  space setting that does that. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686141/wrong-color-in-interface-builders-color-picker

Comment: I tried changing the color profile to both "Apple RGB" and "Generic RGB" and the values were still off.

Comment: Do they LOOK the same when run?

Comment: Yeah they do look the same!

Comment: Please try to set your buttons title colour as: myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.customColor, forState: .Normal)

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all - I'd expect the button text to be black, since 68/255 and the others all evaluate to zero (integer division).