# Color slightly different when reapplying it programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

**EDIT:** This answer solved my problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9203647/1176870

I have some buttons that I'm using as toggles. They start off with the colors rgb(3,61,115) for off and rgb(0,128,255) for on. The colors are initially assigned from the background color selector on the storyboard. This is how they look

[image]

After a user clicks on a button the colors change programmatically with the following UIColors

```
UIColor *on = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:128.0/255.0 blue:1 alpha:1];
UIColor *off = [UIColor colorWithRed:3.0/255.0 green:61.0/255.0 blue:115.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

However, once they change programmatically, the colors are not the same. You can see the change in the image below.

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the alpha and opacity values of the initial one? Looks to me a lot like it could be that. Also i doubt it would have anyhing to do with it, but with floating point is it possible 255.0/255.0 != 1 in this case?

Comment: Probably related: [Wrong color in Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578759/wrong-color-in-interface-builder) and [Weird colors in XCode Interface Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488378/weird-colors-in-xcode-interface-builder)

Comment: @onaclov2000 the alpha for the originals is 1 with a 'Clear Color' tint

Comment: @MatthiasBauch yep, the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488378/weird-colors-in-xcode-interface-builder question answered mine... *sigh* xcode, why you do these things?