# Can't find an option to set a view colour using RGB or hex in XCode 4.2

Tags: xcode, colors, interface-builder, rgb

In XCode 4.2, I want to set a view's background colour to a particular RGB value.  However, I don't appear to have the "RGB Sliders" option that I used to have (perhaps in a previous version).  I'm looking for something like the dialog shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565029/5171) to another question, but all I've got is this:

[image: XCode 4.2 colour chooser]

There are no other options in the drop-down that says "Spectrum".  Does anyone know if/how I can get XCode to accept RGB or hex values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out:

1. Click on the button on the top right of the title bar to reveal the toolbar.
2. Click on the sliders icon.

[image: How to expand the colour dialog]

Seems obvious in hindsight, but if you don't know then you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an RGB color programmatically using the UIColor method [`colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a), then just set it to the view's `backgroundColor` property. I know this isn't the graphical solution you were looking for, but it's somewhat of a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to avoid doing that.  It should be (and previously was) possible to enter the colour into Interface Builder.