# Change UIView's background color like this *FFFFFF*

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.6

On [Facebook iOS SDK Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/#step1)  It reads:

*Add the personal information to the SCViewController that displays when the user logs in. Make these changes in SCViewController.xib:*

*View: In the File Inspector settings, turn off ''Use Autolayout''.*

***View: Change the main view's background color to FFFFFF.***

Question is, In IB, from where can change color of view like this (specifying value). All I know is changing color by using its default picker.

Sorry for the noob Question.

Comment: Same Question was in my mind, when I was reading those docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever wrote this documentation at Facebook wasn't looking closely at the Xcode color picker (and you should file a bug and/or notify them of this fact).

First, you need to convert the hex web color into RGB values, which you can do using some utility or site.  Here's one:  [Color Converter at Yellowpipe](https://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php)

And once you have your RGB values, [you can then enter these into the Interface Builder portion of your main view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565008/how-do-i-enter-rgb-values-into-interface-builder), which looks like this (+1 to Tyler for his answer):

[image: How to choose a color by RGB in Interface Builder.]
<sub>(source: [bynomial.com](http://bynomial.com/tmp/IB_RGB_color.png))</sub>