# How to set Hex color code in xib in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I am not finding an option for Hex color code in xib color picker in xcode.

But I have seen in stack over flow answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27283783/4391112.

In this, image is having Hex color code option in color picker.

**Xcode version : 6.1.1**

How can i get that hex color code in color picker in xib.

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Update: Is there any plugin for xcode to select color in hexa color code. I am using xcode 6.1.1.

or is there any setting in xcode to change the colr in hexa code.

please help me guys

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Select Color Picker From Xib , then choose the RGB Slider from second option Color Slider , now you can Enter HEX color (Below RGB Slider) Codes or Select RGB Values from Sliders.

[image]

Comment: Which version of xcode you are using.  Please tell me. I am using Xcode 6.1.1. Thanks for reply

Comment: thanks jitendra. but i m unable find hex color code option in xcode6.1.1. Any plugin i want to install in xcode.

Comment: In Xcode 61.1, hex code is not showing at all. I dont know what is the reason. One more doubt, I have 2 xcodes(Xcode 5 and xcode 6.1.1). Is that reason I am not having hex code in color picker.Please let me know Thanks

Comment: attached screenshot from xcode 6.1.1 and as you can see color picker properly display  hex code option and having 2 xcode is not the reason for missing hex code in your color picker. please attach related screenshot...

Comment: Hex color input is appearing when selecting RGB Sliders option ONLY! By default it's HSB sliders.

Comment: One more thing to note: Make sure "Show color value as..." is set to 8-bit in the cog/more icon next to RGB Sliders menu, otherwise the Hex Color field won't be visible.

Answer (score 5):

xcode version `11.x`

Within the view controller,

- click on custom for `background`.
- Click on the 3 line rgb sliders tab
- Click `Grayscale slider`
- Choose `RGB Sliders`

[image: xcode version 11.4.1]

[image]